# Gradle Eclipse and Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, gradle, build.gradle

I'm new to Gradle and Jersey but I like them a lot. Currently I'm having some problems I can't understand.

I'm using Eclipse. I've created a simple dynamic web project, with one Java class which has only one "GET" method. Also, I've create a simple index.jsp page that should print out "Hello world". When I copy Jersey jars manually and start my web service from eclipse using "RMC on the project -> Run as... -> Run on web server -> localhost" everything is fine. Eclipse opens up integrated browser and shows "Hello world". Fine.

Now, when I convert my project to Gradle project and create my own build script same prcedure gives me "404" error. No errors while running tomcat server 7 (or 6, it's all the same) nor while running the project. I'm sure it's something related to my build script but I wasn't able to tell what's wrong.

My Gradle build script:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies{
  compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.17'
  compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.17'
  compile 'net.minidev:json-smart:1.2'
  compile 'asm:asm:3.3.1'
  compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
}

sourceSets{
  main.java.srcDir 'src/'
}

war {
    baseName = 'my_webservice'
}
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>my_webservice</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>frontend</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.bsservice</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>frontend</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/desk/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Have you seen the product of the building phase (the directory copied in the tomcat directory)?

Comment: in wtpwebapps, all i can see is WEB-INF folder. Now, when i try to copy (manually) my jsp and manifest files, it works - there's no 404 anymore so i think i have to tell gradle somehow to do it for me

Comment: The behavior can be related to bad directory structure, I read this: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html, probably grandle doesn't find the files in the correct place. Some years ago I had the same problem with maven.

Comment: Hmmm what are you trying to say? Beside java code in my "src", i may also need to put "WebContent" folder there (beside "src")? Project layout is default, created by Eclipse.

Comment: Does that mean you did not use any specific Gradle project creation wizard? You just took an existing project and "converted" it to a Gradle project? If so, converting a project does not automatically put files in the proper folders, it only changes the Eclipse meta information. You might want to start with a fresh project created using one of the Gradle project creation wizards.

Comment: Yes, i did just that! :) I created "Dynamic web project" then converted it to Gradle project (automatic Eclipse conversion) so i can get all the libs i need automatically. When i build new "Gradle project" in the wizard i have only 3 options for "Sample project": "Java quickstart", "Java API and implementation" and "flat-java-multiproject". Which one to pick?

Comment: Probably flat-java-multiproject. The thing with a setup such as Maven or Gradle is that not Eclipse but Maven or Gradle determines what is going to happen - including which libraries are pulled in.

Comment: Ok, and if i want to keep my current code structure (i really don't follow package naming conventions and stuff like that, i like writing code i'm responsible for the way i feel most comfortable), what should i change in the build.gradle? P.S. i'm following "it's my life" coding style :D

Comment: Yeah I suggest you actually learn Gradle first, and when you do don't go against its flow by imposing your own.